# HTML numbering + indent (+hanging indent)

Tags: html, indentation, tex, paragraph, auto-indent

my question is very simple:
i have a numbered paragraph (in Hebrew (right to left language)) and i want the number to be pulled back and the text will be indented, and also hanging indent. like this picture:
[attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJmqG.jpg)

[NEW PICTURE! I NEED MORE INDENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/555A8.jpg)

here is the text, i know that most will not understand it, but here it is anyway:

1. ברוכים הבאים לאתר הבית של חברת השטיח האדום – ייבוא שטיחים בע”מ ( ח.פ  515713212) (להלן: ”החברה”). השימוש באתר זה ובתכנים המוצגים בו (להלן: “האתר”) הינו בכפוף לתנאי השימוש שיפורטו להלן (להלן: “תנאי השימוש”). אנא קראו תנאים אלה בעיון ובקפידה, שכן עצם השימוש באתר ותכניו מעידה על הסכמתכם ואישורכם לאמור בתנאי שימוש אלו.  החברה שומרת לעצמה את הזכות לעדכן תנאי שימוש אלו, מעת לעת לפי שיקול דעתה הבלעדי וללא צורך במסירת הודעה כלשהי מראש. תוקפו של שינוי תנאי השימוש יחל מרגע פרסומו באתר זה. המונח “משתמש” משמעו כל אדם אשר עושה שימוש באתר.
2. בכל מקום בו לא נאמר אחרת, כל מאפיין (feature) חדש באתר, אשר משנה, משפר או מציג בצורה אחרת את השירותים הניתנים במסגרתו, יהיה כפוף לתנאי שימוש אלו. במקרה בו יתווספו שירותים נוספים לאתר, ייתכן ותצטרכו להביע את הסכמתכם הנפרדת לתנאים הנוספים המתחייבים מן השימוש בו.
3. אתר זה נועד לשימוש פרטי בלבד וכל שימוש מסחרי בו ללא קבלת הסכמתה מראש ובכתב של החברה הינו אסור.
4. החברה תהיה רשאית להפסיק ו/או לשנות את שירותי האתר או חלק מהם בכל עת, לרבות את התכנים, המידע והרשאות הגישה הנדרשים לצורך גישה לשירותי האתר, וזאת מבלי הודעה מוקדמת ומבלי שתשא באחריות לנזקים שייגרמו כתוצאה מכך.
5. החברה שומרת על זכותה לסרב להעניק גישה לאתר זה או לחלקים ממנו לכל משתמש, לפי שיקול דעתה הבלעדי וללא התראה מוקדמת.
6. באתר כולל גם מידע ותכנים בעלי אופי אינפורמטיבי ושיווקי. בכל מקרה של סתירה, ידברו תמיד התעריפונים ו/או המחירונים ו/או התנאים הרשמיים של החברה, כפי שהם מופיעים בפרסומים הרשמיים של החברה הזמינים לעיון הציבור במשרדי החברה. בנוסף לכך, כל מבצע ו/או הגרלה ו/או הטבה יהיו כפופים לתקנונים הרשמיים ו/או לתנאים הרשמיים, כפי שיפורסמו על ידי החברה ואשר יהיו זמינים לעיון הציבור במשרדי החברה.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add `dir="rtl"` to the `body` element and the text will be displayed as I understand you want it to be. See the attached snippet and click 'Run code snippet' to see it in action.

If you only want it to be applied to this ordered list, then you can do this:

```
ol {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Explanation:

> The **direction** CSS property sets the direction of text, table
>   columns, and horizontal overflow. Use `rtl` for languages written from
>   right to left (like Hebrew or Arabic), and `ltr` for those written from
>   left to right (like English and most other languages).

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

```css
ol li {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">

  <ol>
    <li>
      ברוכים הבאים לאתר הבית של חברת השטיח האדום – ייבוא שטיחים בע”מ ( ח.פ 515713212) (להלן: ”החברה”). השימוש באתר זה ובתכנים המוצגים בו (להלן: “האתר”) הינו בכפוף לתנאי השימוש שיפורטו להלן (להלן: “תנאי השימוש”). אנא קראו תנאים אלה בעיון ובקפידה, שכן עצם השימוש
      באתר ותכניו מעידה על הסכמתכם ואישורכם לאמור בתנאי שימוש אלו. החברה שומרת לעצמה את הזכות לעדכן תנאי שימוש אלו, מעת לעת לפי שיקול דעתה הבלעדי וללא צורך במסירת הודעה כלשהי מראש. תוקפו של שינוי תנאי השימוש יחל מרגע פרסומו באתר זה. המונח “משתמש” משמעו
      כל אדם אשר עושה שימוש באתר.
    </li>
    <li>
      בכל מקום בו לא נאמר אחרת, כל מאפיין (feature) חדש באתר, אשר משנה, משפר או מציג בצורה אחרת את השירותים הניתנים במסגרתו, יהיה כפוף לתנאי שימוש אלו. במקרה בו יתווספו שירותים נוספים לאתר, ייתכן ותצטרכו להביע את הסכמתכם הנפרדת לתנאים הנוספים המתחייבים מן השימוש
      בו.
    </li>
    <li>
      אתר זה נועד לשימוש פרטי בלבד וכל שימוש מסחרי בו ללא קבלת הסכמתה מראש ובכתב של החברה הינו אסור. החברה תהיה רשאית להפסיק ו/או לשנות את שירותי האתר או חלק מהם בכל עת, לרבות את התכנים, המידע והרשאות הגישה הנדרשים לצורך גישה לשירותי האתר, וזאת מבלי הודעה מוקדמת
      ומבלי שתשא באחריות לנזקים שייגרמו כתוצאה מכך.</li>
    <li>
      החברה שומרת על זכותה לסרב להעניק גישה לאתר זה או לחלקים ממנו לכל משתמש, לפי שיקול דעתה הבלעדי וללא התראה מוקדמת.</li>
    <li>
      באתר כולל גם מידע ותכנים בעלי אופי אינפורמטיבי ושיווקי. בכל מקרה של סתירה, ידברו תמיד התעריפונים ו/או המחירונים ו/או התנאים הרשמיים של החברה, כפי שהם מופיעים בפרסומים הרשמיים של החברה הזמינים לעיון הציבור במשרדי החברה. בנוסף לכך, כל מבצע ו/או הגרלה ו/או
      הטבה יהיו כפופים לתקנונים הרשמיים ו/או לתנאים הרשמיים, כפי שיפורסמו על ידי החברה ואשר יהיו זמינים לעיון הציבור במשרדי החברה.
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: see the new picture i added (i need more indent)

Comment: it's not what i want my friend, i want the space to be between the numbers and the text, i don't need margin from the right side

Comment: @Assaf Did you take a look at the result? It’s adding padding between the number and text.

Comment: isn't "ol li { padding-right: 20px;}" = CSS?
i need it for HTML (it doesn't read well for my use)